# Python 3. Calcular el número de páginas en todos los documentos pdf de un directorio y subdirectorios

Tags: python-3.x, pdf

El código propuesto es el siguiente:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileReader

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])

dir_1= r'C:/CarpetaConPdfs/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir_1):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".pdf"):
            pdf=PdfFileReader(open(os.path.join(root, f),'rb'))
            df2 = pd.DataFrame([[f, os.path.join(root,f), pdf.getNumPages()]], columns=['fileName', 'fileLocation', 'pageNumber'])
            df = df.append(df2, ignore_index=True)
print(df.head)
print("Total de páginas en pdf: ", df['pageNumber'].sum())
```

Pero, con algunas pruebas realizadas, se genera el siguiente error:

- **in getNumPages raise utils.PdfReadError("File has not been
  decrypted") PyPDF2.utils.PdfReadError: File has not been decrypted**

¿Alguien puede ayudarme a solucionar este error, en el código propuesto?

Comment: Has visto esto: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26242952/pypdf-2-decrypt-not-working? menciona varias básicamente dos posibles causas, o el PDF está encriptado, o también se comenta la posibilidad que el nombre del PDF tenga espacios.Revisa el PDF con el que tienes el error, calculo que en las propiedades te debería decir si está encriptado, si fuera ese el problema, al menos tenemos la causa, solo resta encontrar la solución

Comment: Hay 1 solo archivo (de unos 6.000 pdf) con "seguridad mediante contraseña", y que puede ser abierto por Acrobat 7.0 y posterior. Ese tipo de archivos (con "seguridad mediante contraseña") he comprobado, con prueba y error, que es el que genera el error.

Comment: Y, podríamos asumir que los pdf encriptados siempre, pero siempre.. tienen la misma contraseña? por que sino es difícil solucionarlo de forma canonica y tal vez al ser tan pocos, te convendría quitarlos del proceso, informar el path para luego buscar la cantidad de páginas de forma manual.

Comment: Efectivamente. En este caso particular, los pdf encriptados tienen la misma contraseña. Después de mucho investigar (prueba y error), aparecen 2 pdf encriptados con la misma contraseña. Si "elimino" los pdf encriptados, el programa sí funciona. Con los pdf encriptados, cuando se ejecuta el programa sí genera el error mencionado.

Comment: Revisa la documentación de PyPDF2, seguramente hay alguna forma de indicar la contraseña del PDF, podrías capturar el error, y en el caso de los pdf que tengan este error, reintentar el procedimiento pero indicandole la contraseña.